# How to call controller function from directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

how to call controller function from directive? or howto access directive ng-model from controller?
eg. I use angular ui bootstrap time component and when time change I need to notify calling function in controller. 
I think in general it's typical use case for two way communication between components.

```
appControllers.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 
  function($scope) {

    $scope.changedTime = function(time) {
        alert(time);        
    }

 }]).directive('timePicker',['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',    
    templateUrl: 'partials/time-picker.html',
    scope: true,
    controller: 'TimepickerDemoCtrl'        
  };
}]);


//partials/time-picker.html:
<span ng-controller="TimepickerDemoCtrl">              
   <timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>              
</span>


//TimepickerDemoCtrl (copy from source):
var TimepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.mytime = new Date();
  $scope.hstep = 1;
  $scope.mstep = 15;

  $scope.options = {
    hstep: [1, 2, 3],
    mstep: [1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30]
  };

  $scope.ismeridian = true;
  $scope.toggleMode = function() {
    $scope.ismeridian = ! $scope.ismeridian;
  };

  $scope.update = function() {       
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours( 14 );
    d.setMinutes( 0 );
    $scope.mytime = d;
  };

  $scope.changed = function () {
    console.log('Time changed to: ' + $scope.mytime);
  };

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a skeleton app that demonstrates how you can call parent controller functions from directives while using isolate scope to avoid tight coupling (which enhances reusability):

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope){
  $scope.showAlert = function(value){
    alert('Called from directive: ' + value);
  };
})
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      alert: '&'
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.value = 'directive scope value';
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="alert({message: value})">Alert</button>'
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <my-directive alert="showAlert(message)"></my-directive>
</body>
```

[Plunker using this code](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ovKD1klEei7dnUpBSFq?p=preview)

The thing to focus on is the use of the `&` symbol in the `scope: { ... }` setting of the directive. In this case, it provide you with the ability to name the controller function in the `alert` attribute of your directive declaration in the HTML.

That function can then be called from the template of the directive.

Using isolate scope is a common pain point when learning about directives in Angular, but it is well-worth taking the time to wrap your head around.

Regarding the use of `&` in particular, I found [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding) to be especially helpful.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to use `$emit` instead of calling a method of the controller directly in your directive.

Directives should be always independent components, if inside the directive there is a call to  a method from a controller(outside the directive) this will create a dependency between my directive and the controller and of course this will force one not being able to exist without the other.

If I would have to apply a design principle to a directive it will be the S in SOLID, Single responsibility principle. Directives should be able to encapsulate and work independently.

On my controller the event is captured using `$on` like:

```
$scope.$on("ValueChanged", function(event, ars){
   ... //your event has been triggered.    
});
```

Comment: I agree with the basis of your recommendation but not the suggested approach. If they use an isolate scope and assign the controller function in the directive's attributes, they can achieve loose coupling while avoiding polluting their app with lots of events.

Comment: @MarcKline I agree that is also possible but since there is certain ambiguity on the question I decided to recommend a safe approach using $emit which I thought it will simpler to explain and implement.

Comment: Understood. I just think that events are so convenient that they can be overused at the expense of code readability and proper app structuring.

Comment: I think it's the only way to communicate between parent controller and directive controller in code when event like ng-click cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

yes emit/on works also add that when there aren't parent/child hierarchy betwen controllers then it's need to inject $rootScope into subscriber controller.

Comment: That works, but furthering my comment on @Dalorzo's answer, while `$broadcast`s from `$rootScope` will work, others might submit that when you need to do more complex communications between controllers and/or directives, a service is more appropriate.